# Is there any way to list all web services in an application?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, glassfish, mule

How to list all the web services deployed on server? Is there any global command used to list the same?

Like in my services, i have following path in common:

```
path="vms/CaseServices"
path="vms/ActivityServices"
path="vms/FileDownloadServices"
```

and to access them i use

```
http://localhost:8080/vms/CaseServices?wsdl
```

But how to list all web services available on server, whether using Java code?

Comment: I would bet, depending on the server, that there is a xml holding the `Servlet` path, `Filter` path, ... and the `WebService` so you could read that XML to get all the WS. Now, I don't know if it is true, I should check how the mapping is store after the deploy of the `ear`/`war` on the application server

Comment: PS : Of course, if you defined yourself the `web.xml` file to create the mapping, it would be easy to do, but with annotation... this is not as simple.

Answer (score 2):

In Mule you can do it with a transformer:

```
public class HttpPathsTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String encoding) throws TransformerException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("paths: ");
        Collection<DefaultHttpListener> listener = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObjects(DefaultHttpListener.class);
        for (DefaultHttpListener l : listener) {
            logger.info("path: " + l.getPath());
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator()).append(l.getPath());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Logs the paths and returns them as a String.

That are all http paths, not only web services.

Comment: But how to access this?

Comment: Place a JavaTransformer (*not* JavaComponent) in a flow and reference the class above.